# Align vector symbol with upright math letter

Tags: math-mode, fonts, amsmath, math-operators

So basically I need to put a vector symbol (`\vec`) on an upright letter for which I use `\mathrm` in math mode. For example:

```
\vec{\mathrm{E}}
```

While [Katex](https://katex.org/) seems to get the alignment right on all the letters:

[image: Katex]

My pdfTeX version doesn't do so well (using the same code):

[image: pdflatex]

Clearly the vector symbol is positioned such that it would be aligned if the letters were in italic mode.

Which leads me to the following question:

- How can I get the vector symbol aligned with the upright math letter using pdfTeX?

---

#### pdfTeX version

```
$ pdflatex --version
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.2.1
```

#### Document setup

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
```

---

### Complete example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
 \vec{\mathrm{A}}\;\vec{\mathrm{B}}\;\vec{\mathrm{C}}\;\vec{\mathrm{D}}\;\vec{\mathrm{E}}\;\vec{\mathrm{F}}\;\vec{\mathrm{G}}\;\vec{\mathrm{H}}\;\vec{\mathrm{I}}\;\vec{\mathrm{J}}\;\vec{\mathrm{K}}\;\vec{\mathrm{L}}\;\vec{\mathrm{M}}\;\vec{\mathrm{N}}\;\vec{\mathrm{O}}\;\vec{\mathrm{P}}\;\vec{\mathrm{Q}}\;\vec{\mathrm{R}}\;\vec{\mathrm{S}}\;\vec{\mathrm{T}}\;\vec{\mathrm{U}}\;\vec{\mathrm{V}}\;\vec{\mathrm{W}}\;\vec{\mathrm{X}}\;\vec{\mathrm{Y}}\;\vec{\mathrm{Z}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Show a *complete* minimal example, not only some snippets - this makes it much easier to test.

Comment: The glyph used for the `\vec` accent is indeed tailored for best results with italic letters, as the shape of the arrow itself shows. Katex is *not* a TeX engine, so it can't be used for comparison. Beware that `\textrm` is the wrong command in that context, use `\mathrm`.

Comment: `\vec{{}<letter>}` try adding the empty group (or a `\kern0pt`) inside the argument of `\vec`.

Comment: try `\vv{\textrm{E}}` from the `esvect` package

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I assumed the *Document setup* would already contain all the necessary information. Anyway I've added the complete code that produces the posted screenshot.

Comment: @Manuel That didn't work, the alignment didn't change.

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda Thanks for the pointer, however that command seems to change the style of the arrow substantially. I need to use the `\vec` arrow style.

Comment: The `esvect` package takes one optional argument that set the arrows style. The optional argument can be one of the letters a to h the default being d. Try the different arguments one after another to see if one of them does fit your needs. E.g `\uspackage[b]{esvect}`

Comment: @HafidBoukhoulda I tried each of the eight styles and unfortunately none of them matches the `\vec` style.

Answer (score 3):

Before (`\vec`) and after (`\upvec`):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\upvec[1]{\!\vec{\,\mathrm{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\vec{\mathrm{A}}\;\vec{\mathrm{B}}\;\vec{\mathrm{C}}\;\vec{\mathrm{D}}\;
\vec{\mathrm{E}}\;\vec{\mathrm{F}}\;\vec{\mathrm{G}}\;\vec{\mathrm{H}}\;
\vec{\mathrm{I}}\;\vec{\mathrm{J}}\;\vec{\mathrm{K}}\;\vec{\mathrm{L}}\;
\vec{\mathrm{M}}\;\vec{\mathrm{N}}\;\vec{\mathrm{O}}\;\vec{\mathrm{P}}\;
\vec{\mathrm{Q}}\;\vec{\mathrm{R}}\;\vec{\mathrm{S}}\;\vec{\mathrm{T}}\;
\vec{\mathrm{U}}\;\vec{\mathrm{V}}\;\vec{\mathrm{W}}\;\vec{\mathrm{X}}\;
\vec{\mathrm{Y}}\;\vec{\mathrm{Z}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
\upvec A\;\upvec B\;\upvec C\;\upvec D\;\upvec E\;\upvec F\;\upvec G\;
\upvec H\;\upvec I\;\upvec J\;\upvec K\;\upvec L\;\upvec M\;\upvec N\;
\upvec O\;\upvec P\;\upvec Q\;\upvec R\;\upvec S\;\upvec T\;\upvec U\;
\upvec V\;\upvec W\;\upvec X\;\upvec Y\;\upvec Z
\;\upvec{a}
\end{equation*}

\[
\vec A\upvec B f = \upvec D \vec E g
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]